# How do I set permissions on labels in GitHub?

Tags: github, permissions, github-actions, tagging

## Question

Is there some way to set per-label permissions in GitHub?

## Background / Context

I'm working on CI/CD pipelines for a project, the code for which is hosted under a GitHub Enterprise account, using GitHub Actions.

I'm hoping to control the process through labels on a PR.  The manual key points of this process are outlined below:

- When someone creates a PR to master, the CI pipeline kicks off and creates an image and pushes it to AWS ECR.  NB: A lot of other stuff also happens here; e.g. linting, vulnerability scanning, automated testing, etc; but needs no manual involvement.  If things fail the PR is rejected & no image is pushed to ECR.
- The QA team apply the label `ApprovedForUAT` which checks there are no competing labels (e.g. or `ApprovedForUAT` or `DeployedToUAT` labeled PRs; if there are it fails until this is corrected), then kicks off the CD pipeline to deploy that image to our UAT environment.
- Once the image is successfully deployed to UAT, the CD pipeline removes the `ApprovedForUAT` label and applies the `DeployedToUAT` label.
- Once manual testing is completed, the QA team apply the label `PassedUAT` or `FailedUAT` as appropriate; a pipeline checks that the label `DeployedToUAT` had been present to ensure this status update is valid.  If things fail, the image is removed from ECR.
- The release manager then applies the label `ApprovedForProd` (can only be applied if the label `PassedUAT` is already present), causing the CD pipeline to run at a predetermined time to update production with the new image, and removes the `ApprovedForProd` label, and closes the pull request as complete.

## Desired Permissions

The following roles should only be able to apply the given workflow labels:

- QA Team

  - ApprovedForUAT
  - PassedUAT
  - FailedUAT
- Release Manager

  - ApprovedForProd
- GitHub Actions

  - DeployedToUAT

Comment: In my case, only repo owners or maintainers should be able to apply `triaged` label. This label will that all the other labels applied to issue/PR by others have been reviewed and issue/PR is ready to move into development phase.